# Using Shopify how can I capture the customer address on registration and have it saved as the default address for billing and shipping?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am creating a shopify website and I am trying to customize it so when a user / customer registers they can put their address information in at the time and have it saved as their default address. Shopify currently has it so you register then it takes you to an account page where you have the option of adding the address in.

I have tried making form elements on the register page which works as in they show up and get data.
But I don't know how to make the form submit the address data to the default address data locations.
In other words I don't know how to make it store the address as the default address.

I have looked at the code for the actual address page and tried plugin in the id's names and form values in the registration section with no luck. I have tried using id's and names associated with the api customer reference with no luck as well. I can't really find documentation on the subject. There is a section on capturing additional information at registration but its capture as "Notes" not as an address.

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to try to save the address information?  You should be able to just create form elements with the appropriate "name" attribute corresponding to the Shopify "customer" object.

Comment: Need help on this too. Thinking it is not possible actually. There is [a post](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/need-help-adding-new-fields-to-create-customer-account-form-205674) with a suggested naming convention on Shopify forums and one user who said it works, but that was 8 months ago and not sure if it ever worked, but it definitely does not now.

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay. Old question. @NotoriousPet0 I tried just that. And with no luck. If I have access to the code still I will post it. I tried many different things like that with no results.

Comment: @sansjoe In development we decided to move along as we could not find a solution to the problem. I tried using the naming convention with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I created a second account page (customers/account.new-address.liquid) with the address registration form:

```html
    {% assign formID = "" %}
    {% if formInfo.id %}
      {% assign formID = formInfo.id | prepend: "_"%}
    {% endif %}

    {% form 'customer_address', formInfo %}
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <label for="customer_addresses_first_name{{ formID }}">{{ 'customer.addresses.first_name' | t }}</label>
        <input type="text" name="address[first_name]" value="{{form.first_name}}" id="customer_addresses_first_name{{ formID }}" />
      </div>
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <label for="customer_addresses_last_name{{ formID }}">{{ 'customer.addresses.last_name' | t }}</label>
        <input type="text" name="address[last_name]" value="{{form.last_name}}" id="customer_addresses_last_name{{ formID }}" />
      </div>
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <label for="customer_addresses_company{{ formID }}">{{ 'customer.addresses.company' | t }}</label>
        <input type="text" name="address[company]" value="{{form.company}}" id="customer_addresses_company{{ formID }}" />
      </div>
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <label for="customer_addresses_address1{{ formID }}">{{ 'Street Address' }}</label>
        <input type="text" name="address[address1]" value="{{form.address1}}" id="customer_addresses_address1{{ formID }}" />
      </div>
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <label for="customer_addresses_address2{{ formID }}">{{ 'Suburb' }}</label>
        <input type="text" name="address[address2]" value="{{form.address2}}" id="customer_addresses_address2{{ formID }}" />
      </div>
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <label for="customer_addresses_city{{ formID }}">{{ 'customer.addresses.city' | t }}</label>
        <input type="text" name="address[city]" value="{{form.city}}" id="customer_addresses_city{{ formID }}" />
      </div>
      {% if isNew %}
        <div class="input-wrapper">
          <label for="address-country">{{ 'customer.addresses.country' | t }}</label>
          <div class="select-wrapper">
            <div class="selected-text"></div>
            <select id="address-country" name="address[country]" data-default="{{form.country}}">{{ country_option_tags }}</select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-wrapper" id="address-province-container" style="display:none">
          <label for="address-province">{{ 'customer.addresses.province' | t }}</label>
          <div class="select-wrapper">
            <div class="selected-text"></div>
            <select id="address-province" class="new-address-province" name="address[province]" data-default="{{form.province}}"></select>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% else %}
        <div class="input-wrapper">
          <label for="address-country-{{form.id}}">{{ 'customer.addresses.country' | t }}</label>
          <div class="select-wrapper">
            <div class="selected-text"></div>
            <select id="address-country-{{form.id}}" name="address[country]" data-default="{{form.country}}">{{ country_option_tags }}</select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input-wrapper" id="address-province-container-{{ address.id }}" style="display:none">
          <label for="address-province-{{ address.id }}">{{ 'customer.addresses.province' | t }}</label>
          <div class="select-wrapper">
            <div class="selected-text"></div>
            <select id="address-province-{{ address.id }}" name="address[province]" data-default="{{form.province}}"></select>
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endif %}
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <label for="customer_addresses_zip{{ formID }}">{{ 'customer.addresses.zip' | t }}</label>
        <input type="text" name="address[zip]" value="{{form.zip}}" id="customer_addresses_zip{{ formID }}" />
      </div>
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <label for="customer_addresses_phone{{ formID }}">{{ 'customer.addresses.phone' | t }}</label>
        <input type="text" name="address[phone]" value="{{form.phone}}" id="customer_addresses_phone{{ formID }}" />
      </div>
      <div class="inline-input-wrapper">
        {% capture defaultAddressID %}
          {% if isNew %}
            address_default_address_new
          {% else %}
            address_default_address{{ formID }}
          {% endif %}
        {% endcapture %}
        <label for="{{ defaultAddressID | strip_newlines | strip}}">
          {{ form.set_as_default_checkbox }}
          <span class="inline-label">
            {{ 'customer.addresses.set_as_default' | t }}
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-wrapper cta-container">
        <input class="button" type="submit" id="submit{{ formID }}" value="{{ 'general.general.submit' | t }}">
        {% unless isNew %}
          <button class="cancel-edit button secondary">{{ 'customer.general.cancel' | t }}</button>
        {% endunless %}
        {% if customer.addresses.size > 0 and isNew %}
          <button class="toggle-new-address button secondary">{{ 'customer.general.cancel' | t }}</button>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    {% endform %}
```

and then added the following code to the top of the account page (customers/account.liquid) so when a customer accesses the account page after registering and they have 0 addresses on their profile they are redirected to add an address:

```
{% if customer.addresses.size == 0 %}
<meta content="0; url=/account?view=new-address" http-equiv="refresh" />
{% endif %}
```

The ?view=new-address is the link to the alternative account page we created above.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done on the registration form without the use of a third-party app. The solution provided by Muaaz above is the only workaround I'm aware of, and it's a good solution if you're okay with using 2 forms.

You can follow Shopify's [tutorial](https://shopify.dev/themes/customer-engagement/additional-customer-information) to collect address fields (or other custom fields), but these fields are saved only to the customer note. Address fields will not save as the default address.

The [Customer Fields](https://apps.shopify.com/customr) app allows you to collect address fields and save that data as the customer's default address. This is available on the Lite plan, which allows you to collect any standard Shopify fields during registration.